# Is $f': C^1[0,1] \to C[0,1]$ continuous?

Tags: functional-analysis, continuity

Let $C[0,1]$ be the set of continous function on $[0,1]$, and $C^1[0,1]\subset C[0,1]$ be the subset of continuously differentiable functions on $[0,1]$. Equip $C[0,1]$ with the usual supremum metric.
Define $\Phi: C^1[0,1]\to C[0,1]$ by $\Phi(f)=f'$. Is $\Phi$ continuous?

My thought is, as $d(f,g)\to 0$, $f$ and $g$ will eventually be the same, so $d(f',g')\to 0$ as well. So $\Phi$ should be continuous. But I could not prove it with the $\delta-\epsilon$ approach. Can anyone give a hint on the proof or a counterexample?

Comment: Forgive my ignorance. I am a beginner to analysis, this seems obvious, but I couldn't prove it... I tried to prove by definition, i.e. make $\sup |f-g| < \delta$ so that $sup |f' - g'| < \epsilon$. I tried to use the mean value theorem to associate $|f'- g'|$ with $|f-g|$. But the problem is,  as $|f(x) - f(y) - (g(x)-g(y)| \to 0$,  I also have $|x - y|\to 0$, so I cannot trap $|f'-g'|$ into a small range. I suspect I was going in a totally wrong way of doing it...

Comment: It might help to write down the definition of the norm on $C^1[0,1]$.

Comment: I don’t understand how $\Phi$ can be “continuous”—it’s ‘input’ is functions, not real numbers.... There’s no interval for it to be continuous on.

Comment: It shouldn’t seem “obvious”, because it isn’t, at least to me. You can easily construct two functions which are arbitrarily close pointwise, but whose derivatives are very far apart at many points. The thing here is that the norm must make the difference.

Comment: Yes. $\Phi$ is the function of functions. $C[0,1]$ functions form metric space with metric $d(f,g) = \sup_{x} |f(x) - g(x)|$. So we can define continuity on that metric space. Maybe I should be more specific on this.

Comment: @MPW  I thought, if $\sup |f - g| \to 0$, $f$ and $g$ will eventually be the same. So $|f' - g'| \to 0$ as well. Could you give an example of two functions arbitrarily close pointwise, but whose derivatives are very far apart? Thanks.

Comment: @AkiraOsawa As you cleary seem to have thought on the problem, would be good if you edit your answer by adding the comment on what your tried. Might help to reopen the question.

Comment: I guess I’m thinking of sequences with $f_n\to f$ pointwise but $f’_n$ far from $f’$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the sequence of functions $f_n:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ with $f_n(x)=\frac{x^n}{n}$. Then $(f_n)\subset C^1([0,1])$ and $\|f_n\|_\infty=\max_{x\in[0,1]}|f_n(x)|=\frac{1}{n}\to 0$. Hence $(f_n)$ converges to the constant-function $0$ in $C^{1}([0,1])$ with the $\sup$ norm. But $\Phi(f_n)(x)$=$f_n'(x)$=$x^{n-1}$. What is $\Phi(0)$ and does $(\Phi(f_n))_{n=1}^{\infty}$ converge to it in the $\sup$ norm?

Comment: The "standard norm" in $C^1$ is not the sup norm.

Comment: I thought I was referring to objects of the target space $C([0,1])$; I will edit it.

Comment: @AkiraOsawa This probably does not answer your question, since in the standard structures associated to your notation, the statement is true. (We can't say for sure since you **didn't specify the norms**)

Comment: @AloizioMacedo the comments make it clear that both spaces are equipped with the max norm

Comment: @TheGreatSplash The comments make it clear that OP is confused. The only way to make sure of what was intended by **question** (not by OP's attempts) is if he shares the full details on the statement of the **question**.

Comment: I think the discussion here goes beyond my knowledge. I updated the question. Both spaces are equipped with the supremum norm. Sorry for the ambiguity.  @AloizioMacedo Do you mean the statement is true in other norms?

Comment: @AkiraOsawa The space $C^1[0,1]$ has a standard norm (actually, two norms are frequently used, but both are equivalent) which takes into account both the function and its derivative. This norm makes differentiation to $C^0$ a continuous function directly by definition.